# jquery get without submitting form

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, get

I am having an issue with this jquery code I wrote:

```
$('.star').click(function(){

        $('#errors').removeClass().html('');
        var term = $(this).id;
        var posting = $.get("aj_vote_opere.php", { rating: term, opera: '<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>' },
        function(data) {
        $('#errors').addClass(data.stileError).html(data.message);          
    }, "json");
}
```

and my HTML code looks like:

```
<div class="rating">
<span id="5" class="star">&star;</span><span id="4" class="star">&star;</span><span id="3" class="star">&star;</span><span id="2" class="star">&star;</span><span id="1" class="star">&star;</span>
</div>

<div id="errors"></div>
```

In the php file I want to store the vote in DB.
It seems that no GET var is sent.
I guess is because I have no form to submit.
I previuosly used $.post but I realized that no form = no post.
But what with $.get?
I would really appreciate any sort of hint.
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

this is my aj_vore_opere.php:

```
<?php
include('Connections/dbConn.php');

    if(!isset($_SESSION['u_id']))
    {
        $voto_q = "INSERT INTO ar_opere_rating (rate,opera) VALUES ('".$_GET['rating']."','".$_GET['id']."')";
        $voto_x = fln_query($voto_q);

        $msg = $voto_q.'Il tuo voto &egrave; stato correttamente registrato.';
        $bgClass = ' ok';
    }
    else
    {
        $msg = 'Attenzione, devi essere registrato per votare. Vuoi registrarti? <a href="reg.php">Clicca qui</a>';
        $bgClass = ' ko';
    }


    echo json_encode(
        array(
        'message'=>$msg,
        'stileError'=>$bgClass
        )
    );
?>
```

Comment: You are missing a closing brace at the end of the Click handler.. Is that a typo ?

Comment: <<It seems that no GET var is sent.>> Check in your network tab if a request is send or not

Comment: In your code `'<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>'` you should use double quotes instead of single on the outside - `"<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>"`

Comment: yes Sushanth, it was a typo. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Hi face, I have tried both. It seems the problem is not in that.

Comment: I have edited my post. As you can see I am outputting the db query in the responsed message, just for debug.  The query comes with both GET valus void

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works. 
I have also tested this on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pWvrR/1/).
Also check the data your are sending to the server 
`{ rating: term, opera: '<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>' }`.
In your JS you have your object key set as **opera** and you were trying to access that in your PHP via **$_GET['id']**.

```js
$('.star').click(function(){
    var term = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#errors').removeClass().html('');

    $.ajax({
        url: 'path/to/your/server',
        type: 'post',       
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { rating: term, opera: "<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>"},
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            $('#errors')
            .addClass(data.stileError)
            .html(data.message);          
        },
        error: function(xhr, errmsg) {
             console.log(errmsg);   
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: The reason why the opera ID is not getting set is because you set the key in your JS as **opera** and you are trying to access in your PHP as **$_GET['id']**. instead of **$_GET['opera']**

Answer (score 0):

Try This maybe?

```
   $('.star').click(function(){

    $('#errors').removeClass().html('');
    var term = $(this).attr('id');
    $.ajax({
         url:"aj_vote_opere.php", 
         data: { rating: term, id: <?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>},
         dataType: "jsonp",
         success:function(data){
         console.log(data);//for debugging...
         alert(data.message);//for debugging...
         $('#errors').addClass(data.stileError).html(data.message);  
         }
         })
    });
```

Comment: Hi KyleK, thanks for your code. Unfortunately it does nothing. The function in the "done" seems to be not triggered at all.

Comment: Also...are you sure that your aj_vote_opere.php is returning json?

Comment: this is my aj_vore_opere.php:
[code]
<?php
include('Connections/dbConn.php');

 if(!isset($_SESSION['u_id']))
 {
  $voto_q = "INSERT INTO ar_opere_rating (rate,opera) VALUES ('".$_GET['rating']."','".$_GET['id']."')";
  $voto_x = fln_query($voto_q);
  
  $msg = $voto_q.'Il tuo voto &egrave; stato correttamente registrato.';
  $bgClass = ' ok';
 }
 else
 {
  $msg = 'Attenzione, devi essere registrato per votare. Vuoi registrarti? <a href="reg.php">Clicca qui</a>';
  $bgClass = ' ko';
 }

 
 echo json_encode(
  array(
  'message'=>$msg,
  'stileError'=>$bgClass
  )
 );
?>[/code]

Comment: This is what I get from your script:

--
`[12:16:24.550] ({message:"INSERT INTO ar_opere_rating (rate,opera) VALUES ('','')Il tuo voto &egrave; stato correttamente registrato.", stileError:" ok"})`

and is what I get from mine:


--
`[12:17:29.444] {"message":"INSERT INTO ar_opere_rating (rate,opera) VALUES ('3','')Il tuo voto &egrave; stato correttamente registrato.","stileError":" ok"}`

Comment: Try now, you were sending opera as a parameter but should've been sending id, because on your php side, you are looking for $_GET['id'] not $_GET['opera']